# Sharing data between many systems

Tags: c#, architecture

In my working place there are many individual system those are designed for different functional domains. Our management asked me to design a web application which generates reports related to all the system. Now I want to create a common interface which provide information to the website from individual systems. Can anyone give a suggestion about what technology is good for creating such a interface. I am thinking about a creating a web service for this. Is it worth?.
I am using visual studio 2010 and c sharp for creating the website.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of approaches and it depends which approach is most suitable to your requirement and every approach has it's own pros and cons.

Approach #1: Install a Windows Service in every system and push data to a centralized location periodically say, database. Develop a website to get this data and publish reports. But a windows service will be always running in each and every system.

Approach #2: Write a web service and host this in each and every system, it can be WebAPI, WCF or simply WebService. This service will provide data from different systems on demand basis. But it's required to host in every system and may not be performance effective due to on demand accessibility.

Approach #3:  System Center Operations Manager (SCOM) is a cross-platform data center management system for operating systems and hypervisors with a single interface that shows state, health and performance information of computers. Please go through the licensing.

Comment: It's a good answer. Note depending on the reports requirements (need to mix the many systems data, no need to get the last bit of data in the report) the approach #1 can be  amust